# Javascript to Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I'm working on a real estate website now. And everything going fine so far. I found a javascript code on a website, which is also working fine.

I think it is better to have a JQUERY (instead of javascript) because not every browser is supporting javascript etc. (correct me if i'm wrong).

Can someone help me to transform this code to jquery?

Thanks!!

It is the following code:

```
<script>
function showonlyonev2(thechosenone) {
      var newboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
      for(var x=0; x<newboxes.length; x++) {
            name = newboxes[x].getAttribute("class");
            if (name == 'newboxes-2') {
                  if (newboxes[x].id == thechosenone) {
                        if (newboxes[x].style.display == 'block') {
                              newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
                        }
                        else {
                              newboxes[x].style.display = 'block';
                        }
                  }else {
                        newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
                  }
            }
      }
}

    </script>


         <div style="">
            <a id="myHeader1-2" href="javascript:showonlyonev2('newboxes1-2');" >toggle</a>
            <a id="myHeader2-2" href="javascript:showonlyonev2('newboxes2-2');" >toggle</a>
            <a id="myHeader3-2" href="javascript:showonlyonev2('newboxes3-2');" >toggle</a>
         </div>
         <div class="newboxes-2" id="newboxes1-2" style="display: block"><?php the_content();?>
    </div>
         <div class="newboxes-2" id="newboxes2-2" style="display: none;">Div #2</div>
         <div class="newboxes-2" id="newboxes3-2" style="display: none;">Div #3</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. jquery is actually javascript. So in terms of browser support, you are better off with pure javascript. But it doens't really matter these days anymore.

Comment: jQuery is javascript. IF that code is working use it. There's no point in converting it into jQuery and then importing trhe jQuery library to do the same job. It will just add to the load time of the website.

Comment: To be more precise: jQuery is a *library* written *in* Javascript, not a language on its own or anything.

Comment: Thanks guys.. it is working now.. Just with the above code!

Answer (score 2):

> Correct me if I'm wrong

You are wrong. JQuery is a library that makes it easier to do certain things with JavaScript. You use JQuery as part of a JavaScript program, and JQuery is written in JavaScript.

I don't think the rest of your question stands in the light of that, assuming the JavaScript you gave here actually works and does what you want it to.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this code:

```
<script>

jQuery('.myheader').click(function(){
jQuery.find('div').each(function(){
if(jQuery(this).attr('class')=='newboxes-2'){
if(jQuery(this).attr('id')=='thechosenone'){
if(jQuery(this).attr('display')=='block'){
jQuery(this).attr('display','none')
}else{
jQuery(this).attr('display','block')
}
}else{
jQuery(this).attr('display','none')
}
}
});
});
 </script>
```